# change view on - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, segue

How can I change to another view when the app is opened again.

I was thinking of using the method ' - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application ' in my app delegate and performing a segue maybe? How would I go about doing this correctly?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use [NSUserDeafult](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to add the status of application when its go in foreground  and when application opened again means in "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"  just check that NSUserDeafult's value and change ur view.

```
  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  // saving an NSString
  [prefs setObject:@"first" forKey:@"state"];
  [prefs synchronize];
```

use this code when application go in foreground

and when its come back just

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *state = [prefs stringForKey:@"state"];
```

now according to state do whatever u want

Comment: can you give an example? Im using storyboards.

Comment: But with that variable saved lets say I have minimized the app and then opened it again... which method does it check when the app is maximized.

Comment: it doesnt seem to call viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html, check out this link it will help u.

Comment: I understand all the methods available to me in my AppDelegate but that is not what I need now... I need to know how I can check the NSUserDefaults in a current ViewController when my app has just entered the foreground.

Comment: so what method within a ViewController class can I call to check when it is in the foreground again?

Comment: dude i cant give u complete source code. its simple if its go in foreground once again just update nsuserdefault and when its come back just check it, read the NSUserDefault documentation.

Comment: I wrote all the source code.... I just dont know what function to call it in, in the viewController class (once it has entered the foreground).

Comment: ok may b it sud call viewWillAppear, if its not calling that method than u can use notification and u can listen that in viewcontroller. that notification u can dispatch from app delegate.